# WebGL FBO texture with transparent issue

Tags: webgl, textures, transparent, alpha, fbo

So the questions is :
When I am using webgl to render stuff to a FBO, let's say a quad with 512 * 512, if I set the color to be (1, 0, 0, 0.5), which means its alpha is 0.5

Then I use the color attachement as a texture for a sprite, then render it to screen, i found that the alpha does not work.

I searched the question about premultiAlpha, but since my texture is not a image, i don't think it will work.

Even if i use gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);

Still not work.

Any help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: for the record, the whole context, the gl's alpha is set to false.

Comment: solved， sorry to bother